# Apache Portable Runtime install tutorial for windows?

Tags: windows, apache, apr

I want to make use of **Apache Portable Runtime**. Does anyone know how to install and configure APR for windows?? Please suggest.

Comment: follow the link https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html

Answer (score 1):

1. APR can be built on Windows, I did it once myself too :-) Just follow the description presented [here](http://apr.apache.org/compiling_win32.html). It is true, that they present us the MS C++ build system and an older version of it but works.
2. You can download the latest Apache Web Server release for Windows and simply use the provided APR libraries.